# libpenni2 vs Occipital Openni2 (repository)

Tags: ros, libopenni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Folks,
To use the Asus pro live with my personal projects (using the header files, etc.), what drivers are better, the libopenni2 (that come with openni2_launch ROS package), or the occipital repository? I ask this because I try to use the openni2 tracker with openni2_launch, but it crashes (not always, but from time to time). And I cannot find out how old the libopenni2 files are compared to the occipital OpenNi2 files.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240444/libpenni2-vs-occipital-openni2-(repository)/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2016-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Pototo. Unfortunately, the openni2_tracker and the openni2_launch cannot run at the same time. If you need both the skeleton tracker and the data (point cloud, image, etc...) from the Asus Xtion Pro Live, you can try [this](https://github.com/Chaos84/skeleton_tracker).

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-08-02**:
There is this repository that I use, but it crashes some times:
https://github.com/ipa320/cob_people_perception/tree/indigo_dev/cob_openni2_tracker

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-08-02**:
Before it crashes, this repository allows me to run openni2_launch and track a skeleton at the same time. I need color image, depth image, and skeleton at the same time unfortunately.

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-08-02**:
Do you know of any Xtion Pro packages that allow you to display those images? Maybe I can take that code and add it in the cob_openni2_tracker to see if that reduces errors.